# Operating an iPad with broken touch screen

Tags: macos, ios, ipad

Can I use software from my computer to operate an iPad with a broken touch screen?

Comment: With Jailbreak maybe with out jailbreak unlikely.  I did this on the original iPhone.  You are going to need a way to imagine a vnc software along with configuration files onto the tablet.  Because of Apples new security mechanism it will be more difficult then it used to be.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't if it's broken in a way that touch no longer registers. You need to tap on the screen to enter your passcode - even on Face ID models with some regularity.

Once it's unlocked, you can 100% connect it to a USB-C hub and have mouse, keyboard and display all be remote. As long as you can unlock it, it makes a very powerful "computer" when connected to a hub.

I used my old iPad Pro with FaceID this way for over a year with a pretty severely crushed screen. I went to an Apple Store and they let me trace out the outline of the key pad for unlock and the keyboard layout (I initially had an alphanumeric passcode - that once it became a "home only" device, I turned into a 6 or 8 digit passcode for ease of typing "in the blind." It's now going to be scrapped, as the damage has now spread to the capacitive touch layer and I can no longer reliably unlock it.

Comment: The Magic Keyboard as well as third-party equivalents is a substitute for the touch screen. It even includes Touch ID on some models.

Comment: No they do not. I have a broken iPad Pro with FaceID and the Apple Magic Keyboard and it only works when I could enter via touch screen the passcode at boot @ATL_DEV - mine is without TouchID but I’ll see if I can get an Apple Store to let me test my broken iPad with the latest keyboard. I would love it and buy that keyboard as I hate to see this iPad lie fallow as long as there is life in an external display.

Comment: Strike the last one. I sent you the Magic Keyboard, not the iPad Magic Keyboard.  The minimalist naming causes a lot of confusion. Take a look at this page: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211091

Read the section "Connect your Magic Keyboard to your iPad." It doesn't mention anything about pairing it. Wake your iPad with your Magic Keyboard
To wake your iPad, press any key on your Magic Keyboard. Another keypress will bring up the Lock Screen. Unlock your iPad with Face ID or Touch ID, or you can enter a passcode with your Magic Keyboard or by tapping on the screen as usual.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I own a iPad 11" Pro and I purchased it with a broken screen and I managed to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. There is no other way to control an iPad than by its touch screen. There are limited keyboard controls, but nothing that can replace touch functions.

(If you could get to accessibility settings, you *could* enable [switch control](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201370), but you would need to use the touch screen first.)

Comment: Not true. According to Apple the Magic Keyboard doesn't require any pairing or authentication to work.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can. There are several solutions depending on the extent of the damage. Most require additional hardware:

1. External display adapter.
   [image: Display Adapter]
2. iPad Keyboard with trackpad (non-bluetooth)
   [image: Magic Keyboard]
3. OTG USB Hub with generic wired keyboard and mouse
   [image: USB Hub OTG]
4. iPad docking station.
   [image: iPad Docking Station]
5. Mac running QuickTime connected to iPad (see below)

#### No Touch input, but working display

If your touch input no longer works, but the display does, you can use an external USB keyboard and mouse connected to a OTG USB hub or a docking station (option 3).

The easiest solution, however, is to use an iPad keyboard and trackpad for input (option 2). The Magic Keyboard is an excellent choice, but there are numerous less expensive options available.

Make sure neither the keyboard nor the mouse is wireless, otherwise have no way of pairing them if your input isn't working to begin with.

#### Working Touch input, but no display

If the display no longer works, but the touch does, you can use an external video adapter or docking station connected directly to an external monitor (Option 1 or 4). Alternatively, you can use QuickTime to mirror the display to a Mac using a USB cable (option 5).

#### No Touch input, and no display

If both the display and the touch don't work, you can use a hub connected to an external keyboard and mouse, or an iPad keyboard with trackpad (Option 2 or 3). The display can be mirrored to a Mac using QuickTime to mirror the iPad (Option 5, see below).

The far easier solution, however, is to use a docking station connected to a keyboard, mouse and external display. (option 4)

#### Mirroring your iPad's display to a Mac

You can mirror you iPad display directly on a Mac using Quicktime as a viewer.

1. Connect your iPad to your Mac using your Lightning to USB cable.
2. Open the **QuickTime Player** app on your Mac.
3. Choose **File > New Movie Recording**.
4. Click the **Options** pop-up menu, then choose any of the following recording options: **Camera: Choose your connected iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch.**

### ASIDE

The OP is ambiguous as to what was damaged and its extent. The term "touchscreen" can refer to only the LCD, only the digitizer, or both components. Moreover, a partially damaged digitizer can be responsive in the region where the passcode is entered, yet be non-responsive in other regions making it unusable. Consequently, I initially answered the question detailing the display since it's what is usually mean by touchscreen.

I've since addressed the issue of a failed digitizer. However, the OP didn't ask for how to bypass, or how to workaround entering passcode without a malfunctioning digitizer. While strongly discouraged, an iPad or iPhone can be configured without any biometric or passcode security.

That said, there are three ways of entering or getting around the passcode issue. Some may or may not work.

1. If you connect a keyboard via USB, you can double press the  spacebar  to activate the Lock Screen where you can enter the passcode.
2. According to Apple the Magic Keyboard doesn't require any pairing or authentication to work.
3. You can also use iCloud to completely erase the phone and passcode. You can connect your keyboard and use it to setup the iPad again without a Passcode. Of course, don't do this unless you don't care about the data on your device.

Comment: How does this help OP control the iPad with a broken touch screen? Your solution just seems to offer screen recording.

Comment: I added some additional information after rereading the post.

Comment: I am skeptical you can enter the passcode for the device after an iPadOS upgrade or in any of the instances listed under set or change a passcode. https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/set-a-passcode-ipad997daf9f/ipados Would you be willing to test this and edit the post explaining how you can change the passcode with no touch screen interaction and external devices that won’t be trusted until you enter a passcode with touch?

Comment: -1 for now as the USB hub only works once you have an unlocked iPad. That can’t help this OP since the touch screen is broken. (They may be able to see the screen but not touch it )

Comment: @AndyGriffiths, Reread my question and answer.